# Question got wrong answer on SO, but was answered correctly on SU

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, wrong-answers

[This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862446/vimdiff-failing-with-cannot-read-or-write-temp-files) has a bad accepted answer.

Normally I'd just give another answer, and downvote and comment on the wrong answer. But, the [same question was asked on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/697847/cant-run-vimdiff-7-4-on-windows-7) where I already gave the correct answer some time ago.

What's the best thing to do here? I assume duplicating answers between sites is frowned upon.

Comment: Since we cannot close cross-site dupes *and* the question is on-topic on both sites, I see no issue with you re-using your answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Make it an answer?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: done, with expansion.

Comment: Is it really so hard for you to write up a short form, and point to the older answer? Duplicating content is just wrong, even if it *is* your own.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since we cannot close cross-site dupes and the question is *on-topic on both sites*, I see no issue with you re-using your answer on Stack Overflow.

We only frown upon re-using of answers when *on the same site* because you should be closing the question as a duplicate in the majority of cases, or tailor your answer to the question if the issues really are different.

Since that's not the case here, and it is your own answer, you as the author can reuse your own text on multiple Stack Exchange sites without issue or the need to cite.

Comment: What about just linking to the other answer since it's part of the same network of websites.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Then it'd be a link-only answer. These cases are rare anyway, I am fine with a repost *by the same author*. If not the same author, make it a clearly quoted piece, with attribution and original content (e.g. the other post should support your answer, not *be* your answer, preferably).

Comment: It might make sense to link (in addition to quoting, i.e. not link-only), so that if and when the answer becomes obsolete and/or a better answer arises, someone who updates it in one place will be aware of the need to update it in the other too (or conversely if it's updated in one place people reaching the other might also find a lead to the updated answer).

Comment: Thats a bug cross-site dupes should be closable.

Comment: May I point out that the *same* user posting it on two different sites is frowned upon? It's usually not that big of a deal, but where cross posting happens, usually it's off topic on one of the sites.

Comment: This question is a rather unusual case in that it is explicitly on topic for two different sites. Normally, you'd close one of them as off-topic without any need for a cross-site duplicate. Besides, each site is supposed to be independent. Closing as a duplicate of a question on another site would be the moral equivalent of a link-only answer. @casey

Comment: @Tom Actually, you'd want to cross-link both directions.

Comment: @Yakk - Of course :-)

Comment: @CodyGray naw your ethics is getting in the way of your normalization...there are was of doing it which will look Kool and provide a good experience for the user and not offend the individual sites...if I can think of a few so can you

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just ran into a case where [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590443/compile-entire-boost-library-c-ubunutu) is a cross site dupe of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168053/how-to-install-all-the-boost-development-libraries).  would it be okay to copy the answer, properly attribute it, and make it a CW?

Comment: @NathanOliver: post is gone now. But with proper attribution you can reuse the work from Ask Ubuntu, making it a CW post is recommended. Just make sure the question is not just a crosspost and is on topic here.